# ValueInjecter and DataTable

Tags: c#, automapper, valueinjecter

I was trying to figure out ValueInjecter so i can use it in our  home-grown little ORM. Since i should support DataRow and DataTable mapping, i am trying to implement mappers for this types. And honestly documentation is not good enough and i wanted to give it a shot. Maybe Omu or some other users of this library will answer.

here is my DataRow injector

```
public class DataRowInjection: KnownSourceValueInjection<DataRow>
    {
        protected override void Inject(DataRow source, object target)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < source.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
            {

                //TODO: Read from attributes or target type
                var activeTarget = target.GetProps().GetByName(source.Table.Columns[i].ToString(), true);
                if (activeTarget == null) continue;

                var value = source.ItemArray[i];
                if (value == DBNull.Value) continue;

                activeTarget.SetValue(target, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

this works pretty well. so here is the question how can i implement this for DataTable and return Ienumarable or IList. the code snippet i expect to do is like.

```
public class DataTableInjector  : ?????
    {
        protected override void Inject(DataTable source, IList<T> target)   where T : class
        {

          // Do My Staff
            foreach (var row in source.Rows)
            {
                target[i].InjectFrom<DataRowInjection>(row);
            }

            //return IList?
        }
    }
```

How can i accomplish this. 
Thank you

~~~~~~ here is complete code i wrote with Omu's help

```
 public class DataTableInjection<T> : ValueInjection where T  : new()
    {
        protected override void Inject(object source, object target)
        {
            var dt = source as DataTable;
            var t = target as IList<T>;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                var t2 = new T();
                t2.InjectFrom<DataRowInjection>(dr);
                t.Add(t2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: awesome :), looks pretty simple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same as you did it for `DataRow`, you just use `KnownSourceValueInjection<DataTable>` now.

Also as you can see the `Inject` method is `void` so you don't return anything you just change the target object (which already exists).

Remember that `InjectFrom` doesn't create new objects, it injects values into an existing one.

So you are going to have:

```
var list = new List<T>();
list.InjectFrom<MyFromDataTableInj>(dataTable)
```

Actually in your case you are going to use this injection only from DataTable to `IList<T>`
so you could do like this:

```
   public class My<T> : ValueInjection
   {
        protected override void Inject(object source, object target)
        {
            var dt = source as DataTable;
            var t = target as IList<T>;
... 
        }
    }
```

And usage:

```
list.InjectFrom<My<Foo>>(datatable):
```

Comment: i managed to accomplish what i was trying to do and edited question. thanks again.